# How to regexp replace something not in comment?

Tags: c#, regex, comments

How using regexp replace something in code that is not a comment?

```
..PATTERN.. PATTERN // .. PATTERN ..
```

to

```
..ANOTHER.. ANOTHER // .. PATTERN ..
```

Comments can be `//` or `/* */`

Regexp to find comments is:

```
/\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/|(//.*)
```

Comment: Your regex to find a comment will mess up the following source: `string s = "... // ...";`.

Comment: @Gumbo, I would assume C# because it's tagged as C#.

Comment: @Corey Ogburn, yeah, probably, but the OP could be processing C# code with some other tool/language...

Comment: To be more precise: What language do you want to remove these comments from?

Comment: C# or C++ . Comments can be find by /\*(.|[\r\n])*?\*/|(//.*)  as  described in this article: http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html

Comment: to be more concretic I want to remove namespaces before types, that declared in "using", but live it in comments. This I need to properly compare code with another version of it (SVN)

Comment: Take a look at [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278739/regular-expression-for-clean-javascript-comments-of-type/4278816#4278816). This might also be applicable to C#/C++.

Comment: @newGuest, that article ends with a "Caveats" paragraph explaining when it doesn't work (as my example `string s = "... // ...";` clearly shows)

Comment: I remember tackling this problem in my compiler construction class....it wasn't exactly trivial. We couldn't do this with regexp due to the issue Bart described. We needed to define states in the lexer...and nested comments were an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this for single line comments by using a negative lookbehind (but still prone to problem of literal string of the form "....//....."):

```
string target = "replace // don't replace";
var output = Regex.Replace(target, "(?<!//.*)replace", "new string");
Console.WriteLine(output); //  new string // don't replace
```

Maybe this could work for multiline:

```
string target = 
    @"replace;
/*
* don't replace
*/
replace;
    ";

var output = Regex.Replace(target, @"(?<!./\*\s*)replace(?!\s*\*/)", "new string", RegexOptions.Singleline);

Console.WriteLine(output);
```

output:

new string;
  /*
  * don't replace
  */
  new string;

Comment: thank you, I must read about advanced regex assertions. But your multiline sample will be broken after adding "* don't replace SOMETHING". Also if you dont know this is online test http://regexhero.net/tester/ with ability of generate .NET code

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple two-state scanner (REGULAR_TOKEN, COMMENT_TOKEN, ....)

Then for each REGULAR_TOKEN do a straightforward replace, and leave the comment_tokens. Once again I recommend Boost Spirit/

If you specified your goal/problem more, I might whip up an example

Comment: here is my code exemple:  protected List<Mogre.OverlayContainer> mThumbs = new List<Mogre.OverlayContainer>(); //comments: Mogre.OverlayContainer is for bla-bla-bla

Comment: with this simple regex   (.*?)Mogre\.   I can remove namespace, but it also remove it from comment